# How to map drive to WebDAV server using self-signed certificate?

Tags: windows-10, ssl, webdav

I have an ownCloud WebDAV server with a self-signed SSL certificate, running on a public IP address, no domain name.  In Windows 10 Pro, when I try to map a network drive using SSL, I get error: "Network logon failed".  I don't see anything in Event Viewer, but I assume the problem must be related to the certificate.  If I try without SSL then it works.

Using MMC, I have imported my certificate to the Current User > Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

I also enabled Basic Authentication in the registry, although I'm not sure if that's needed for Windows 10: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters\BasicAuthLevel = 2`